# I want to keep the assets folder inside the application folder not outside

Tags: codeigniter, assets

My question as in the title

I want to keep the assets folder which contain `(css, js, images)` inside the application folder not outside.
If I keep the `assets` folder inside the application folder, I can't access to the files that inside it.

**.htaccess file code**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

**The standard Application structure:**

- Application

  - **app**
  - **assets**
  - sys
  - .htaccess
  - index.php

The previous structure has no errors.

**I want the structure to be like the following:**

- Application

  - **app**

    - **assets**
    - config
    - controllers
    - ......
  - sys
  - .htaccess
  - index.php

How can I do that ?

Comment: well you can't because they are outside the webroot of that app.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: @Matthew Daly: because I want all my application files in one folder Which is app folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `.htaccess` file you're using is rewriting the URL of your static assets, breaking the links, so you need to change it.

If you keep your `assets/` folder inside the root of the application and amend your `.htaccess` to something like this, that should solve the issue:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

The change is on the second line - essentially the condition is "If the route doesn't start with index.php, assets, or robots.txt, then rewrite it to include index.php at the start". The addition of assets should solve the issue.

EDIT: By default, CodeIgniter has an .htaccess file inside the `application/` folder that denies access to anything inside it. If you really, really want to be able to serve your static files from that folder, you can amend that file. However, it would be a really bad idea. Your static assets should live in the web root, and trying to serve them from the application folder will be fraught with problems - if you allow access to the `application/` directory from outside, it could cause some serious security issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did it, but it does not solve the problem, and I have got this message `You don't have permission to access`.

Comment: Then change the permissions to that folder to allow read access. In Unix or Linux that would be chmod a+r assets

Comment: @LionKing It still sounds like a permissions issue, but as I never touch Windows I can't tell you how to resolve the permissions